# filter freemarker output by hash

Tags: freemarker

```
<#list reports as report>
<#list report.transactionList as expense>
    ${expense.transactionID}^<#t>
    ${table[expenses.transcationID}
    <#if expense.modifiedCreated?has_content>
      ${expense.modifiedCreated}^<#t>
    <#else>
      ${expense.created}^<#t>
    </#if>
```

In the above code I have a hash table called table and I want to use expense.transactionID as the key to then load the table's value like in the above code. 
when I run it, the second item instead of a value is just a blank spot.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out. {table[expenses.transcationID} needs to cast the category I am using as the key into a string. so the answer is:   {table[expenses.transcationID?string}

Comment: Assuming that `table` uses `String` keys on the Java side... Otherwise, for non-string keys, you have to call the Java API of the `Map`: `table?api.get(expenses.transactionID)`.